# Is there a way to query XML data without explicitly using field names?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wondering if I can generalize this query so the user does not need to know the names of the fields?

My current query looks something like this:

```
USE [VideoGameProject]
DECLARE @myXML = "'<review><rating>97</rating><gameid>2</gameid><reviewdate>11/03/2017</reviewdate><reviewtitle>Super Mario Odyssey : A Masterpiece</reviewtitle><headline>Mario embarks on his greatest adventure yet!</headline></review>';

SELECT
value.value('(/review//rating/node()[1]', 'int') as Rating,
value.value('(/review//gameid/node()[1]', 'int') as GameId,
value.value('(/review//reviewdate/node()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as DateOfReview,
value.value('(/review//reviewtitle/node()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as TitleOfReview,
value.value('(/review//headline/node()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Headline

FROM GameData;
```

I was hoping to do a generic query, something where I don't need to explicitly write all of the field names, maybe a SELECT * equivalent?

I see the above query to be a little error prone. I understand the @myXML variable is not necessary, but wanted to give a reference.

If anyone can help, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, you can use the ordinal location of the nodes (elements and attributes).

You'd need to adapt this for your need, but it would look something like this...

```
DECLARE @myXML AS xml
SET @myXML  = '
<review>
    <rating>97</rating>
    <gameid>2</gameid>
    <reviewdate>11/03/2017</reviewdate>
    <reviewtitle>Super Mario Odyssey : A Masterpiece</reviewtitle>
    <headline>Mario embarks on his greatest adventure yet!</headline>
</review>
';

SELECT @myXML.query('/node()[1]/node()[1]/node()[1]') AS [Rating]
SELECT @myXML.query('/node()[1]/node()[2]/node()[1]') AS [GameId]
SELECT @myXML.query('/node()[1]/node()[3]/node()[1]') AS DateOfReview
SELECT @myXML.query('/node()[1]/node()[4]/node()[1]') AS TitleOfReview
SELECT @myXML.query('/node()[1]/node()[5]/node()[1]') AS Headline
```

And, if your XML isn't in a variable, you can query it directly from a table.

One table for demonstration purposes:

```
CREATE TABLE #foo (id int identity(1,1), things xml)

DECLARE @myXML AS xml
SET @myXML  = '
<review>
    <rating>97</rating>
    <gameid>2</gameid>
    <reviewdate>11/03/2017</reviewdate>
    <reviewtitle>Super Mario Odyssey : A Masterpiece</reviewtitle>
    <headline>Mario embarks on his greatest adventure yet!</headline>
</review>
';

INSERT INTO #foo (things) VALUES (@myXML);
```

Now, we've got a table with one record of XML data. Here is one way to select it out...

```
SELECT things.value('/node()[1]/node()[1]/node()[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS [Rating]
FROM #foo
```

Here is another...

```
SELECT things.query('/node()[1]/node()[1]/node()[1]') AS [Rating]
FROM #foo
```

Comment: Cool, let me look into this. Is there a way to not use my declarations in the SELECT?

Comment: I apologize. I didn't have my coffee this morning. When you say declarations, what did you mean? I didn't quite follow.

Comment: No, it's my fault - I just mean, is there a way to not use @myXML.query..if not, that's cool, and I appreciate the help, regardless.